# jQuery slideToggle more than one panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

Im a complete noob when it comes to JavaScript and jQuery but here we go.

I want to make a slidetoggle that shows 3 slides, 3 "snowboardtricks" when i press "toggle".

As it is now only one "trick" is shown when i press toggle, the rest is already there from the beginning.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#flip").click(function()
    {
        $("#panel,#panel2,#panel3").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
#panel,#panel2,#panel3,#flip
    {
        padding:1px;
        text-align:left;
        color:white;
        background-color:black;
        border:solid 1px yellow;
    }
#panel
    {
        padding:5px;
        display:none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="flip">Toggle</div>
<div id="panel">Switch back 1080 double cork</div>
<div id="panel2">Frontside triple cork 1440</div>
<div id="panel3">Ollie</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, on page load you only want to display "Toggle". When you click "Toggle" you want to show the three other sections.

To do that you want to place the three other sections inside of a wrapper div, and then use slide toggle on the wrapper div instead.

Quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/43byX/

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#toggle").click(function() {
                    $("#drawer").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
             #toggle,
            .panel {
                padding:1px;
                text-align:left;
                color:white;
                background-color:black;
                border:solid 1px yellow;
            }

            #drawer {
                padding:5px;
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div id="toggle">Toggle Me</div>
        <div id="drawer">
            <div class="panel">Switch back 1080 double cork</div>
            <div class="panel">Frontside triple cork 1440</div>
            <div class="panel">Ollie</div>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This was exactly was i was after.

Comment: @Glufse no problem. If this answer satisfies your question make sure to accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems what you're trying to do can be more easily accomplished using accordion.

[Quick jFiddle example here. Click the headers to see the effects.](http://jsfiddle.net/eAFyv/)

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(function() {
    $( "#flip" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
```

You can erase the active code if you want one of the panes to be open when the page loads, and you can erase the collapsible line if you want one of the panes to always remain open.

and then the html layout:

```
<div id="flip">
<h3>Switch back 1080 double cork</h3>
    <div><p>some text or whatevs here</p></div>
<h3>Frontside triple cork 1440</h3>
    <div><p>some text or whatevs here</p></div>
<h3>Ollie</h3>
    <div><p>some text or whatevs here</p></div>
</div>
```

[Read more about accordion here.](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Edit: It may be better to put the

```
<script>
 $(function() {
    $( "#flip" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
 });
</script>
```

just before the closing body tag instead of in the header. Best practices would have you put it in a separate file and link it in the header.

Answer (score 0):

```
#panel, #panel2, #panel3
{
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
}
```

You are in essence hiding only the div whose id is panel. But the other two div's are visible. Those need to be hidden as well. This way when you toggle all three will have their displays turned to true.

On a side note is there a reason you are creating your own toggle? It might be faster to use twitter bootstrap which already comes with it. [See This](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to toggle that one hidden element one by one. Well, If I am not wrong, then here is the code:

```
$("#flip").click(function(){
    var targets = $("#panel, #panel2, #panel3"),
        hiddenElm = targets.filter(":hidden");

    hiddenElm.slideDown();

    if(hiddenElm.next().length){
        hiddenElm.next().slideUp();
    } else {
        targets.first().slideUp();
    }
});
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/jg2wg/